# To get partial character

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
jitter (Index: 1200) to 223.28.1.xxx ; 
jitter (Index: 900) to 223.28.0.xx ; 
jitter (Index: 700) to 223.28.1.xxx ;
```

How do I get partial character that starts from '223 until end' ?
Currently, I am using the substring (resource_name,24), but my solution is not suitable as it unable to fulfill all new requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use substring with position(substring in string)
It tells the position of the 223 in your string. More info in [PostgresSQL Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-string.html)

Like this:

```
SELECT substring(resource_name, poisition('223' in resource_name))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below query

```
select substring(resource_name,locate('223',resource_name)) from <table_name>
```

for more string functions [click here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_locate)

Comment: Posgres did not recognize 'locate'

Comment: @SamilaMohdZain sorry i missed the postgres tag. the above will work fine in mysql